# SQL nested INNER JOIN Freezing PHPmyadmin panel

Tags: sql, nested, sum

I'm trying to work out a query for a game server.

What the below SQL is intending to do is finds all the people using a "sniperRifle" of which there are multiple types, it then SUMS up the kills for each weapon for each individual player.

I've written the below SQL to try and achieve this, but every time I've tested SQl similar to this the PHPmyAdmin panel stops working and I have to ticket the host to have it fixed.

Is there a better way to perform the below query or a way to fix it so it doesn't freeze.

*

```
SELECT pd.SoldierName, ks.Kills
FROM tbl_playerdata pd INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sp.PlayerId, SUM(ws.Kills) as Kills
    FROM tbl_weapons w, tbl_server_player sp, tbl_weapons_stats ws
    GROUP BY sp.PlayerID) ks
on w.Damagetype = "sniperrifle" and w.WeaponID = ws.WeaponID and sp.StatsID = ws.StatsID
WHERE pd.PlayerID = ks.PlayerID
ORDER BY Kills DESC, SoldierName;
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the conditions that limit your inner query results from the outer query to your inner query should give some performance improvements since it's easier for the optimizer to limit the number of combinations generated;

```
SELECT pd.SoldierName, ks.Kills
FROM tbl_playerdata pd INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sp.PlayerId, SUM(ws.Kills) as Kills
    FROM tbl_weapons w 
    JOIN tbl_weapons_stats ws ON w.WeaponID = ws.WeaponID 
    JOIN tbl_server_player sp ON sp.StatsID = ws.StatsID
    WHERE w.Damagetype = "sniperrifle"
    GROUP BY sp.PlayerID) ks
ON pd.PlayerID = ks.PlayerID
ORDER BY Kills DESC, SoldierName;
```

If this does not give enough of an improvement, you'll need to run some form of `EXPLAIN` (depending on your RDBMS) to show what indexes - if any - are used or missed.